# SVG rendering artifacts in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I've noticed that, when repainting filled SVG paths (due to color/opacity changes triggered by mouse event handlers, for instance), the repaint is sometimes glitchy on Chrome:

[image: Artifact on Chrome]

I haven't seen this behavior in Firefox, Opera, or Safari (haven't tested IE yet.)

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Some more details: the SVG in question is generated by d3, and makes heavy use of `<use>`, `<clipPath>`, and `<g transform="...">`; the screenshot you see uses CSS `opacity` rules, but I've seen the same thing from updating the `fill` color in CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Can you create a jsBin to duplicate the issue?

Comment: If you haven't already, please file a bug with a complete testcase that shows the issue at http://crbug.com.

Comment: @ErikDahlström - haven't done that yet!  Thanks for the link; I'll submit a bug report when I find the time to do so :)